# Jest shows only one test suite, even when multiple top-level calls to describe() exist in the test file

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm testing my library with jest, and have a file with several describe calls at the first layer, but when I run "npm test", It reports:
"Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total"
"Tests: 26 passed, 26 total"

Why isn't it reporting several test suites?

As far as I can tell, jest's describe function should create its own test suite, but somehow they're all being combined...

From the jest API,
"describe(name, fn) creates a block that groups together several related tests in one test suite"

Comment: It only reports the top level describes in that way I think, the number of files.

Comment: There are multiple top level describes though, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Have you tried splitting them between files to see if it makes a difference? Why is the number of suites so important?

Comment: It isn't really, it's just annoying. I want to know if I'm doing something incorrectly

Comment: Did you add at least one line of functional code to those new test suites? Jest skips empty test suites and empty tests, hence - they may disappear from results.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for actual testing, it's just the reporting when I run it

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Jest does not really count every top-level call to `describe()` as a single Test Suite. There's even an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7434) in Jest's GitHub repo reporting this behavior as a bug.

Indeed, as you described and as this [minimal example on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BlaringMedicalZip) demonstrates, two top-level calls to `describe()`:

```
const add = require('./add');
describe('add', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
describe('add again', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    expect(add(1, 0)).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Are counted as a single Test Suite:

```
Jest v22.1.2 node v7.4.0 linux/amd64

 PASS  ./add-test.js
  add
    ✓ should add two numbers (5ms)
  add again
    ✓ should add two numbers

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.025s
```

[Current Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html#describename-fn) appears to misleading when it states:

> `describe(name, fn)` creates a block that groups together several related tests in one "test suite"